# EF Core error : duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am getting this error when I try to Add an entity to the database  after I switched from injecting the DbContext directly into the DI to using DbContextFactory:

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.  ---> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_Departamente"`

In the Entity (ModificareInregistrare) I want to add, I have a reference to a Department that exists in the database. I am pretty sure that ef core tries to add this Department to the database.

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ..
    public Guid DepartamentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Departament Departament { get; set; }
    ..
```

This is the call:

```
        var modificare = _mapper.Map<ModificareInregistrare>(request.ModificaInregistrareDto);
        var op = await _dbContext.ModificariInregistrari.AddAsync(modificare, cancellationToken);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

The DbContext is created from IDbContextFactory

```
    public CreateModificareInregistrareCommandHandler(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> contextFactory, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _dbContext = contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
```

Departament class looks like this (trimmed alot of properties):

```cs
public class Departament : SoftDeleteEntity<Guid>, IRepartizabil
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Numele departamentului
    /// </summary>
    public string Nume { get; set; } = "";

    /// <summary>
    ///     Prescurtarea numelui
    /// </summary>
    public string Prescurtare { get; set; } = "";

    /// <summary>
    ///     Id parintelui pentru organigrama
    /// </summary>
    public int? DepartamentParinteId { get; set; }


    public ICollection<ComentariuDepartament> Comentarii { get; set; } = new List<ComentariuDepartament>();

    public virtual ICollection<RepartizareUtilizatorDepartament> RepartizariUtilizatori { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RepartizareUtilizatorSecretariatDepartament> RepartizariUtilizatoriSecretariat
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Registru> RegistrePermise { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ModificareInregistrare> ModificariInregistrari { get; set; }

}
```

LE: This is the important part of the Modificare object that is sent to AddAsync method:
[image: debug info]

The Departament is null and the DepartamentId is set.

LLE : Started getting the error after switching from a scoped DbContext to a DbContextFactory with Transient scope. Thing is, this is the only place where I get this error . I am adding Entities with DepartamentId set and Departament null , and I don't get this error.

SOLVED:
Inside the Modificare class I had another reference Registru and RegistruId , and inside Registru there was a List of permitted Departaments . I updated the DTO profile from automapper to ignore the Registru reference (set it null) and now there is nothing referencing the Departament and the error is gone .

Comment: Try changing Tracker status to unchanged for this entity

Comment: Error: System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'ModificareInregistrare.Id' has a temporary value while attempting to change the entity's state to 'Unchanged'. Either set a permanent value explicitly, or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property.

Comment: Side note: don't use `AddAsync`, see the info in intellisense.

Comment: You still don't show all essential code. It's all about the content of the `modificare` object. We don't see that. I *assume* that it has a populated `modificare.Departament`. Avoid that. Only set `modificare.DepartamentId`.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by this

```
 var modificare = _mapper.Map<ModificareInregistrare>(request.ModificaInregistrareDto);

 modificare.Departament  = _dbContext.Departament.FindAsync(modificare.Departament.DepartamentId);

 var op = await _dbContext.ModificariInregistrari.AddAsync(modificare, cancellationToken);
 await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Or

```
var modificare = _mapper.Map<ModificareInregistrare>(request.ModificaInregistrareDto);

_dbContext.Entry(modificare.Departament).State = EntityState.Modified;

_dbContext.ModificariInregistrari.AddAsync(modificare, cancellationToken);
 await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

These two approaches will help EF Core to know that the row department with that specified primary key already exist, and track the existing from database instead of inserting new one.

Second way, you can also solve it by this

```
 var modificare = _mapper.Map<ModificareInregistrare>(request.ModificaInregistrareDto);

 modificare.Departament  = null;

 var op = await _dbContext.ModificariInregistrari.AddAsync(modificare, cancellationToken);
 await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Edit :

Since the above code does not work, I believe the reason for the issues might be this property inside `Departament`  class.

```
public virtual ICollection<ModificareInregistrare> ModificariInregistrari { get; set; }
```

Since this is a reverse Navigation properties to the `ModificareInregistrare`, it will in turn re-refer back to the `Departament` unfortunately this time it will have same primary key to with its granparent of `Departament`

ModificareInregistrare

```
 --- Departament

    --- ModificareInregistrare

       --- Departament

           --- ModificareInregistrare
```

thus the repeating instance will cause the error.

You can solve it using this way

```
var modificare = _mapper.Map<ModificareInregistrare>(request.ModificaInregistrareDto);

modificare.Departament.ModificariInregistrari = null;

_dbContext.Entry(modificare.Departament).State = EntityState.Modified;

_dbContext.ModificariInregistrari.AddAsync(modificare, cancellationToken);
 await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: First two approaches I get 'Error: System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Departament' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: a5feeb04-df28-4221-88c0-b7bb1058d1a7}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.' . Second way, I get the same error 'duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_Departamente"' . "Departament" was already null from the mapping ...

Comment: Can you please share the model for `Departamente` ?

Comment: Edited . Added the Departament Class. Departamente is the DBSet<Departament> . What intrigues me , is that I have many entities that reference an existing Departament when added and are working as intended with the same code.

Comment: Ok, I think I find something that might cause the issues. I will edit my code now.

Comment: Can't set 'modificare.Departament.ModificariInregistrari = null;' because Departament is null . Will try removing the ICollection reference ...